# How to search and use a file in ssh/server

Tags: c++, ssh, server

My c++ program is being run on xCode. One part of my program is searching for a file that's on my computer and using it to store the values into an array. Everything is working just fine on xCode, but when I moved my files .cpp .h .txt into a server or ssh it doesn't seem to be working.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
case 'W':
            if(heap.capacity == 0)
                cout<< "Sorry!!! It cannot be done. Please initialize the heap first.";
            else{
                file.open("/Users/mbojo/Downloads/HEAPinput2.txt");
                int line;
                int count = 0;
                while(file>>line)
                    count++;
                file.close();
                heap.capacity = count;
                cout<< "COMMAND: " << choice << "\n" << "The capacity is "<<
                heap.capacity << "\nSize is " << heap.size<<endl;
            }
            break;
```

Is there anything I need to change in ssh/server that can read the file.

Comment: How are you recompiling on the server after you move the files over to it?

Comment: Well, I am just adding files onto the server

Comment: Well, what is the server? Does it have the same OS and architecture as the computer you are building on? If not, the is no way the executable will run on the server. Further, you haven't mentioned moving the *executable*. Moving a C++ source file and header and text file won't run themselves without the C++ file being compiled to object and then linked into an executable. Are you sure you have all the pieces to this puzzle in the right place?

Comment: I forgot to mention, I made a makefile containing all of the programming files and also added it to ssh. I ran the make file on my server, but it doesn't work

Comment: I'm guessing, but you still haven't identified the OS/hardware for your original build box and the server. If you created a make file, and then after copying everything to the server, you ssh in and run `make` and receive no errors and check that the executable was built -- then there is no reason it shouldn't run (still ssh'ed in and you do `./myexecutable`. More info is needed.